# My new iMac connects to my router, but not to the internet. How to fix?

Tags: wifi, imac, internet

I have a 3 week old 2012 27-inch iMac and this morning I turned it on and it wouldn't connect to the internet. It connected to my home network just fine, just not the internet. I assumed it was my router's fault, but every other device in the house connected to the internet just fine. I have already tried turning it off and on again, many times, as with my router. I have also tried turning the Wi-Fi off and on in System Preferences. Any help?

Comment: Is your router set up with the default settings, or have you made modifications such as enabling port-forwarding, static IP's, etc.

Comment: What's the iMac's IP address? Does it start with 169? To check, go to Apple Icon in top left corner > System Preferences > Network > Make sure Wifi is elected on the left pane > It should say "Connected" and the IP below that.

Comment: Could you open a Terminal, type within `Terminal` the command: `ifconfig en1` and insert the oupput within your original question. This will help network engineers to help you.

Answer (score 1):

You are connecting your Mac to the router via WiFi.

The first thing to check is that your Mac is asking for an IP address and your router is giving it one.

Open System Preferences > Network and select "Wi-Fi" in the left hand pane. On the right is should say "Wi-Fi is connected to [router name] and has the IP address [IP address]"

If it does you have a deeper problem, if it doesn't say that but instead says it has a self-assigned address that start with 169 then you have a DHCP problem.

Click on the "Advanced…" button at bottom right and in the Advanced pane click on "TCP/IP". Make sure that "Configure IPv4" is set to "Using DHCP" and then click on "Renew DHCP Lease" and see if you now get a good address.

if you are getting a good address from your router then try something simple, run "ping -c 5 google.com" on the command line and you should see ping send and receive 5 packets.

If neither of those work then please run `ifconfig` at the command line and you will see a number of blocks starting with an interface name of "en" followed by a number. Your wireless is probably "en1" or "en0". Paste this output into your question and we will have a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

By "turn it on/ off," do you mean you rebooted the computer? Apple sign in the top left corner > Restart. Sorry if this seems obvious. Just have to start simplest first.

If you have tried rebooting, try the following:
1. Unplug your modem and router
2. Wait a full minute
3. Plug in your modem
4. Wait a full minute
5. Plug in your router
6. Wait a full minute
7. Check internet connections now

Comment: Elliot wrote:
    …Wi-Fi off and on in **System Preferences**.
And this is sufficient to fire a DHCP renewal, without going through the waste of time of a reboot. A reboot is the rule of thumb rule to fix anything when you are running an OS of really poor quality.